# How to rotate the angle the unwrap is applied to the object with

Tags: uv

I made the mistake of clicking proportional editing in UV Editing and later forgetting about it. Going back to UV Editing, the edges would remain proportional when moving vertices, which I didn't want.

Eventually, after some troubleshooting, I disabled proportional editing.

During troubleshooting, the unwrap has been rotated 90 degrees when wrapped around the object:

[image: How to rotate the angle that the unwrap is applied to the object]

How do I rotate the angle at which the unwrap is applied to the object? (-90 degrees on the Y plane, I believe).

I've tried the following:

[image]

but the Rendered image is unchanged:

[image]

**Edit**

It is not clear how I rotate the image in UV Editing so that the 2d wrap aligns properly with the 3D object: https://i.imgur.com/kDpB1Ly.mp4

Comment: It seems you try to use the compositor to rotate the image. You need to use the UV editor instead.

Comment: I see @lemon, if I rotate the unwrap on the left of the UV editor: [https://i.imgur.com/kDpB1Ly.mp4](https://i.imgur.com/kDpB1Ly.mp4), the image still doesn't align properly on the object on the right. The rotate tool for the object on the right is not the solution either.

Comment: @lemon I found `Face > Face Data > Rotate UVs` in the window on the right solved the problem. Unsure if that's what you meant, as Blender is complicated *as* for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the object editor on the right of *UV Editor*, using `Face > Face Data > Rotate UVs` was the solution:

[image: How to rotate the angle the unwrap is applied to the object with]